# Linq with dot notation - which is better form or what's the difference between these two?

Tags: c#, linq

I've been reading Jon Skeet's [C# In Depth: Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471) and I noticed something slightly different in one of his examples from something I do myself.

He has something similar to the following:

```
var item = someObject.Where(user => user.Id == Id).Single();
```

Whereas I've been doing the following:

```
var item = someObject.Single(user => user.Id == Id);
```

Is there any real difference between the two? I know Jon Skeet is pretty much the c# god so I tend to think his knowledge in this area is better than mine so I might be misunderstanding something here. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Even Gods make mistakes. Just look at California

Comment: @Dismissile: WTF? California is heaven on Earth.

Comment: @Jason. Substitute California for your most hated state/place then :) The place might be nice and sunny but the people are retarded ;)

Comment: @Dismissile: The people in California are no different than the people anywhere else, except they are smart enough to not be living anywhere else.

Comment: @Jason: Oh yeah...them peoples in Hollywood are geniuses.

Comment: @Dismissile: Are you telling me that Pulp Fiction does not kick ass?

Comment: What the heck is all the above?

Comment: @MyNameIsJob: A tangential conversation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The queries should be equal when the tree is evaluated, however depending on the target the actual execution could differ (IE L2S optimization).

Answer (score 3):

I typically *think* in terms of "filter then take a single value". On the other hand, when it comes to `Count` I'll often use the version with the predicate. For `Any` I can go either way pretty easily depending on my mood :)

Ultimately it's unlikely to make any significant difference - use whichever is easier to understand at the time. I certainly wasn't trying to *avoid* using the versions with predicates etc - and I give some examples using them on P499.

While there are some situations with "definitely more readable" versions, many other cases are pretty much equally readable either way.

Comment: I didn't expect a reply from you - while you're answer is exactly what I was looking for the accepted answer does give me the same information - plus you have enough reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can notice is that the IL produced using the Where method is one row bigger than the second example (tested through LinqPAD).

```
IL_0042:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Where
IL_0047:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Single
```

instead of a single call to `System.Linq.Enumerable.Single`

```
IL_006B:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Single
```

Comment: This is quite logical behavior.

Comment: Yes :) I just want to point that it seems to be only a difference in IL code. Using Single instead of Where+Single will be more performant in JIT compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for Linq2Objects, I personally prefer using the `Enumerable.Single(this, predicate)` version directly, simply because adding the `Enumerable.Where` will introduce an additional enumeration which `Enumerable.Single` will pull the data from.

By using `Enumerable.Single` directly on the primary enumerable, no additional enumerations are started. I have never benchmarked this to evaluate the real performance impact, but why execute more code when you don't need to right? Especially if readability is not impacted, of course this last point is rather subjective.